# How do you store credentials in redis specific to the user that logged in through OAuth2.0?

Tags: python, redis, google-oauth

I have an app with a Google OAuth login that saves documents to Google Drive. The issue is, no matter who is logged in, all documents get saved under one user's name (mine).

Here is my OAuth callback route:

```
@app.route("/oauth2callback")
def oauth2callback():
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    flow.redirect_uri = url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)
    authorization_response = request.url
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
    credentials = flow.credentials
    credentials_dict = credentials_to_dict(credentials)
    credentials_bytes = pickle.dumps(credentials_dict)
    redis_client.set('credentials', credentials_bytes)
    oauth2_client = build('oauth2','v2',credentials=credentials)
    user_info = oauth2_client.userinfo().get().execute()
    user_bytes = pickle.dumps(user_info)
    redis_client.set('user', user_bytes)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Here is the first part of the function that uploads the file:

```
def upload_file():
    try:
        credentials_bytes = redis_client.get('credentials')
        credentials_dict = pickle.loads(credentials_bytes)

        credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(credentials_dict["token"],
            refresh_token = credentials_dict["refresh_token"],
            token_uri = credentials_dict["token_uri"],
            client_id = credentials_dict["client_id"],
            client_secret = credentials_dict["client_secret"],
            scopes = credentials_dict["scopes"])

        drive = googleapiclient.discovery.build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)
```

Now, I'm pretty sure the issue is in the way I'm storing 'user' and 'credentials' through redis. They're not being set dynamically per user, creating just one user/credential pair for the app.

I've Googled as much as I can and tried different syntax variations to make this work. I think it's supposed to be something like this:

```
redis_client.set(f'credentials:{user_identifier}', credentials_bytes)
```

but I can't get it to work properly when calling it in the upload_file() function. It still uses only my credentials.